# How do i move the mouse with processing?

Tags: processing

I was testing processing features and wondered if I could move the mouse with code with/without libraries. So can anyone write me a code / give me a library so that it works?

I tried reading half the 284 questions and found nothing, I tried reading through github trying to find a code / a library that works.

Comment: What are the 284 questions? In any event, this might help: https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/move-mouse.html

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a potential workaround:

Using `noCursor();` you can get rid of the default cursor, and then develop your own custom cursor using something like shapes.

E.g. `circle(mouseX + 20, mouseY, 20);` would always draw a "cursor" 20 pixels to the right of where your mouse position actually is.

This is how I made a custom and dynamic cursor for a little game, where it changed color and sometimes position depending on activities on the screen.